# Text input is carrying over in multi step form

Tags: reactjs

So I'm using React to create a multistep form for new users to fill out. I haven't looked up if there is a standard way to do multistep forms, so this is just my rendition. The problem is that if in step one the first question is "First name" and I put "John", "John" will appear in the text input for the first question in step 2.

```
          <form onSubmit={handleOnboardInfo}>
              <Grid>
                <Grid>
                  {form[currentStep.step].map((stepInput, i) => {
                    if (stepInput.type !== "yes-no") {
                      return (
                        <Grid key={'form_input_'+i}>
                          <FormControl>
                            <TextField
                              onChange={(event) => {
                                handleChange(event);
                              }}
                              defaultValue=''
                              aria-label={stepInput.label}
                              label={stepInput.label}
                              name={stepInput.name}
                              type={stepInput.type}
                              required={stepInput.required}
                            />
                          </FormControl>
                        </Grid>
                      );
                    } else {
                      return (
                        <Grid key={'form_input_'+i}>
                          <FormControl>
                            <FormControlLabel
                            onChange={(event) => {
                                handleChange(event);
                              }}
                              name={stepInput.name}
                              control={<Checkbox />}
                              label={stepInput.label}
                              required={stepInput.required}
                            />
                          </FormControl>
                        </Grid>
                      );
                    }
                  })}
                  {currentStep.step === 0 && (
                    <Button
                      disabled={!currentStep.completed}
                      onClick={() => {setCurrentStep({step: currentStep.step + 1, completed: false, inputsCompleted: 0})}}
                    >
                      Next
                    </Button>
                  )}
                  {currentStep.step === 1 && (
                    <Button
                      onClick={() => {setCurrentStep({step: currentStep.step -1 , completed: false, inputsCompleted: 0})}}
                    >
                      Back
                    </Button>
                  )}
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </form>
```

Here are my state variables

```
const [form, setForm] = useState();
const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState({
    step: 0,
    inputsCompleted: 0,
    completed: false,
  });
const [formData, setFormData] = useState([
    {},
    {}
  ]);
```

And here are relevant functions

```
// Get initial form
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getForm() {
      let formData = await axios.get("/api/onboarding");
      formData = formData.data.steps;
      setForm(formData);
    }

    getForm();
  }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
    if (form) checkForStepCompletion();
  }, [formData]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    const newFormDataKey = event.target.name;
    const newFormDataValue = event.target.type ==='checkbox'? event.target.checked:event.target.value ;
    const newList = formData.map((item, index) => {
      if (index === currentStep.step) {
        const updatedItem = {
          ...item,
          [newFormDataKey]: newFormDataValue,
        };
        console.log(updatedItem);
        return updatedItem;
      }

      return item;
    });

    setFormData(newList);
  }

  function checkForStepCompletion() {
    let counter = 0;
    let stepItems = formData[currentStep.step];
    for (let item in stepItems) {
      if (stepItems[item]) {
        counter++;
      }
    }
    setCurrentStep({
      ...currentStep,
      inputsCompleted: counter,
      completed: counter == form[currentStep.step].length,
    });
  }
```

Comment: What does `handleChange` do?  What's in your `form` variable?

Comment: Could you post the structure of your state variables? Are you using class components or hooks to track state?

Comment: @David, form is an array of arrays, each internal array holding all the inputs for a certain step, handleChange is shown above now

Answer (score 0):

Because the input of each step has the same key `key={'form_input_'+i}`. So just change the `key` prop of Grid to

```
<Grid key={currentStep.step + i}>
```